# Generating multiple graphs/plots from uploaded files in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm new to Shiny (worked with R for a few months) and i'm trying to figure out what a 'Shiny' way of handling multiple uploaded files is.

My goal is to have an interface where the user can upload multiple files. From these files a report must be generated, in the form of a large number of graphs and plots. From what I learned in the Shiny tutorials, on the server side all objects are isolated from eachother (meaning they cant be read, unless you call another function explicitly).

As you can see in my code below, this means that I have to duplicate the processing code for every single plot. This seems inefficient. What would be the 'Shiny' way of handling this?

Also, i left out a bunch of code that is not absolutely necessary for the example. In essence, I need to do a lot more processing and i dont want to duplicate all that code for every plot.

**I am specifically asking about the server-side code. I want to read in multiple files that contain different contents. The operations in the server-side code are just place-holders, I don't actually want to cbind anything but I put that there to keep this code simple. I want to be able to do whatever I want to the imported data frames.**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Sidebar with file input
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            fileInput("people", NULL, multiple = FALSE, accept = ".csv",
                      buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "people file"),
            fileInput("info", NULL, multiple = FALSE, accept = ".csv",
                      buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "info file"),
        ),

        # Show the results of the data processing
       mainPanel(
           imageOutput("plot"),
           tableOutput("base_data")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to process the data
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$base_data <- renderTable({
        if(is.null(input$people) | is.null(input$info)) {
        } else {
            people_file <- input$people
            info_file <- input$info

            people <- read.csv(people_file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
            info <- read.csv(info_file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

            rbind(people, info)
        }
    })

    output$plot <- renderImage({

        if(is.null(input$people) | is.null(input$info)) {
            outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
            png(outfile, width = 1200, height = 800, res = 200)
            dev.off()

            list(src = outfile, width = 1200, height = 800)
        } else {
            people_file <- input$people
            info_file <- input$info

            people <- read.csv(people_file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
            info <- read.csv(info_file$datapath, stringsAsFactors = F, fileEncoding = "UTF-8-BOM")

            outfile <- tempfile(fileext='.png')
            png(outfile, width = 1200, height = 800, res = 200)
            plot(nrow(people), nrow(info), type="b")
            dev.off()

            list(src = outfile, width = 1200, height = 800, alt = "questions"))
        }
    }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here's an example of what i want in pseudocode:

```
[[ui]]

fileInput("people")
fileInput("info")

show(plot)
show(plot2)
show(df)


[[serverside]]

files <- source(input) {
  people <- read.csv(input$people, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  info <- read.csv(input$info, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
}

contents <- plot(output) {
  some_function(files$people, files$info)
  plot(contents)
}

contents2 <- plot(output) {
  some_other_function(files$people, files$info)
  plot2 <- plot(contents2)
}

df <- table(output) {
  cbind(files$people, files$info)
}
```

This is in pseudocode what i have now, which is not efficient.

```
[[ui]]

fileInput("people")
fileInput("info")

show(plot)
show(plot2)
show(df)


[[serverside]]

contents <- plot(input, output) {
  people <- read.csv(input$people, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  info <- read.csv(input$info, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  contents <- some_function(people, info)
  plot(contents)
} 

contents2 <- plot(input, output) {
  people <- read.csv(input$people, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  info <- read.csv(input$info, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  contents <- some_other_function(people,info)
  plot(contents)
}

df <- table(input, output) {
  people <- read.csv(input$people, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  info <- read.csv(input$info, stringsAsFactors = F, encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")
  cbind(people, info)
```

}

Comment: Hi enzolima. Even though you have removed a lot of unnecessary code, there is actually still a lot of code that is not really relevant to the actual question, which, as far as I can tell, is how to generate multiple outputs (e.g., table and plot) from a single object. There are definitely 'Shiny' ways of doing this, but it's much easier to show that with a more minimal reproducible example.

Comment: i trimmed it down. is this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will have to agree with heds1 thats a bit difficult to get your desired result. Since we dont have access to your csvs i created some dummy ones.

**Reproducible data / csvs:**

```
write.csv2(x = 1:5, file = "people.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv2(x = 6:10, file = "people2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

If i understand you correctly you would like to avoid repeating the code for every uploaded file.
In order to loop over your files/ datasets we will have to collect them in one data structure.

One way of doing so would be to allow upload multiple files:

```
fileInput(..., multiple = TRUE)
```

**Ui Side:**

The ui side you could create with a loop in `renderUI()`:

```
output$plots <- renderUI({
  lapply(paste("people", 1:length(data)), plotOutput)
})
```

**Server side:**

The server side you can create with a loop over:

```
output[[paste("people", nr)]] <- renderPlot({
          plot(plotData)
})
```

**Local assignment**

Finally you will have to use `local()` to avoid that only the data of the last iteration of the loop is taken:

```
      local({
        LOCAL_VARIABLE <- data[[nr]]
        ....
      })
```

**Full reproducible example:**

```
library(shiny)

write.csv2(x = 1:5, file = "people.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv2(x = 6:10, file = "people2.csv", row.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "people", label = NULL, accept = ".csv",
            buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "people file", multiple = TRUE),
  uiOutput("plots")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$people, {
    data <- lapply(input$people$datapath, read.csv2)    

    for(nr in 1:length(data)){
      local({
        plotData <- data[[nr]]
        output[[paste("people", nr)]] <- renderPlot({
          plot(plotData)
        })
      })
    }

    output$plots <- renderUI({
      lapply(paste("people", 1:length(data)), plotOutput)
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:**

Reuse the imported (and transformed) data:

```
library(shiny)

write.csv2(x = 1:5, file = "people.csv", row.names = FALSE)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput(inputId = "people", label = NULL, accept = ".csv",
            buttonLabel = "Browse...", placeholder = "people file", multiple = FALSE),
  plotOutput("plot"),
  tableOutput("table"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  global <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$people, {
    data <- read.csv2(input$people$datapath)
    # DO LOTS OF OPERATIONS ON data

    global$data <- data
    # FROM HERE ON USE: global$data
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(global$data)
    plot(global$data)
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    global$data
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    toString(global$data)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think my original question was not clear. The input files will contain different types of information. For example, a file with "people" and a separate file with information about them, "info". I cross-reference those files to create a plot. I removed all of this code because heds1 said it was not necessary. But i don't want to loop my inputs, I need 4 separate input fields with 4 separate names. I'm only talking about the server-side code.

Comment: ok party understood. You could elaborate at which stage you would duplicate code? Would it be the case if a user uploads files for a second/third time? Would you replace the "old" ones or do you want to show the "new" plots next to the new ones?

Comment: a user should upload "people.csv" and "info.csv". If they upload a different "people.csv", it should just replace the older "people" dataframe.

to reiterate: there is no such thing as uploading 2 people.csv files for my request. there can be 1 of each file at a time.

Comment: could you elaborate at which stage you would duplicate code? (or avoid to dupliate,..)

Comment: I have updated the original question. In the serverside, I have to import the uploaded files for every single output that i want. I want to import the files once, then do different operations on them, and have an output for each operation. Right now, i must repeat the code to import the files for every single output that i do.

Comment: My goal is to avoid duplication in the server-side script.

Comment: ah ok. I think i have a better understanding now. It seems to me you are looking for `reactiveValues()` or `reactive()` functions. See my edit.

Comment: thank you! this solved it. I can not award the bounty until 22 hours from now, but after that i will.